# /sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.5 is not a symbolic link

Tags: 16.04, symbolic-link, shared-library

I keep getting this error:

```
fmf@kodi:~$ sudo ldconfig  
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.5 is not a symbolic link
```

Any idea on how to fix it?

```
fmf@kodi:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release: 16.04
Codename: xenial
```

Comment: What is the ouput of ls -l /sbin/ldconfig.real and ls -l /usr/lib/libstdcc++.so.5?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The most likely cause is that there are two files with almost the same name with identical contents, and one should be a symlink to the other, but is not. Here are two files in my `/usr/lib` that are OK

```
libgimpui-2.0.so.0 -> libgimpui-2.0.so.0.800.16
libgimpui-2.0.so.0.800.16
```

(This symlink is so that programs that look for `libgimpui-2.0.so.0` will find the newer version)

You apparently have `libstdc++.so.5` and a related file such as `libstdc++.so.5.300.0` or maybe `libstdc++.so.6` and their contents are exactly the same. Do `cd /usr/lib; ls` and see if this is the case.

Check that the two files are the same, for example do (replace the correct filename in this command):

```
diff libstdc++.so.5 libstdc++.so.[rest.of.filename]
```

If they are the same, `diff` returns no output.

**If and only if they are the same**, delete `libstdc++.so.5` and make a symlink to the other file with that name.

```
sudo rm libstdc++.so.5
sudo ln -s libstdc++.so.[rest.of.filename] libstdc++.so.5
```

---

Based on [this question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11542255/ldconfig-error-is-not-a-symbolic-link)