# Cannot set LD_LIBRARY_PATH in /etc/profile.d

Tags: command-line, nvidia, bash, environment-variables, mate

I have installed nVidia CUDA 7.5 in Ubuntu Mate 16.04. However, I am having trouble setting up the environment variables.

Here is the `nvidia-settings.sh` file that I have in `/etc/profile.d` folder:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-7.5/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-7.5/lib64:/usr/lib/nvidia-361:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/nvidia-361:/usr/local/cuda-7.5/lib64:$LIBRARY_PATH
```

However, after reboot the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment was not automatically available. Here is the terminal output that shows the issue:

```
ponir@mate:~$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH

ponir@mate:~$ echo $LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/lib/nvidia-361:/usr/local/cuda-7.5/lib64:
ponir@mate:~$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-7.5/lib64:/usr/lib/nvidia-361:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
ponir@mate:~$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/local/cuda-7.5/lib64:/usr/lib/nvidia-361:
ponir@mate:~$
```

But after executing `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-7.5/lib64:/usr/lib/nvidia-361:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in Terminal I could get that variable.

What could be the issue?
Thanks.

Comment: You should have done `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `echo $LIBRARY_PATH` to see if these two environment variables exist.

Comment: `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` gives a blank output as well.

Comment: Can you update your question with the output from using `echo`? That removes the "No such file or directory" noise that is distracting us from the core of your question.

Comment: I have recreated the issue in a new terminal and this time using echo. I have updated the question.
I think there is something wrong in my `nvidia-settings.sh` file. But cannot figure out what!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Ubuntu wiki help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#File-location_related_variables)

> Note: You can only set this environment variable inside an interactive
>   shell. [ie a terminal ] Since Ubuntu 9.04 Jaunty Jackalope, LD_LIBRARY_PATH cannot be
>   set in $HOME/.profile, /etc/profile, nor /etc/environment files. You
>   must use /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf configuration files. See Launchpad
>   bug #366728 for more information.

How to fix it:

```
cd /etc/ld.so.conf.d
```

Make a file with the `.conf` extension here

```
sudo nano cuda.conf
```

Add the paths to it as two lines

```
/usr/local/cuda-7.5/lib64
/usr/lib/nvidia-361
```

Save and exit. Check with `ls -l` that the file has the same ownership and permissions as others in the directory, they should be:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root
```

Then run

```
ldconfig
```

This doesn't set the env variable, but includes the libraries appropriately so CUDA works

Comment: I do remember setting up `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in Ubuntu 14.04. And it worked there. The problem with `ldconfig` is that it gives an error with `libcudnn.so.4` files (cuDNN v4): `/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/local/cuda-7.5/lib64/libcudnn.so.4 is not a symbolic link` as these are non standard library. And packages need `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable in order to load cuDNN.

Comment: You can do it in your `.bashrc` (sourced by interactive shells) but the `ldconfig` method is apparently preferred...

Comment: You should be able to fix that error from `ldconfig` : see [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/805643/527764) @ponir

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should have installed cuda through apt-get.

With that said, when you compile stuff like this from source code, you often need to run the following command:

```
 sudo ldconfig
```

If there isn't some reason to have a compiled version installed and if the version available from apt-get is sufficient for your needs, I would suggest uninstalling the compiled version and installing the version from apt-get instead.

Run the following commands for more info:

```
sudo apt-get update 
apt-cache search cuda | grep -i cuda
```