# Dynamically load specific version of shared library

Tags: package-management, shared-library, gstreamer

My distro is shipped with pre-installed gstreamer, and its `.so` files are in `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/`

I want to use a more recent version which I compiled from source; installed in `/usr/local/lib`

So now I have a problem - any call to `gst-launch` or `gst-inspect` tries to load the older libraries and, naturally, fails to work.

I tried to remove gstreamer package but quite a lot of other packages depend on it (and I don't want to break anything).

What should I do?

Comment: Simplest solution `LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/ gst-launch`, but probably it wouldn't work for you as you want it to be always ran with the library. You could set the variable to `/etc/environment`, though. Anyways, I don't have a time to research an answer, but probably setting `rpath` in gst-launch and gst-inspect via `chrpath` command should do the trick.

Comment: @Hi-Angel for some strange reason neither works. LD_PRELOAD gives the same error of undefined symbol; chrpath gives: open: No such file or directory
elf_open: No such file or directory"

Comment: From the error about "No such file…" I'd guess that either a file you want to set rpath to, or from, is missing. "Undefined symbol" is strange, but what do you mean by `the same error`, did it appear before?

Comment: @Hi-Angel The same error meaning the same as without LD_PRELOAD. Prepending command with LD_LIBRARY_PATH (as suggested by smurf) did the trick.

Comment: See also [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/807872/cannot-set-ld-library-path-in-etc-profile-d/807880#807880) for info, although using `ldconfig` to link the libraries in your situation is probably unsafe since other programs depend on the preinstalled version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct command is:

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/your/path/to/newer/gstreamer/libs gstreamer`