# libcudnn.so.6 is not a symbolic link

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, opencv

While installing libopencv-dev using `sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev` i get following comments:

```
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) ...
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/local/cuda-8.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcudnn.so.6 is not a symbolic link
```

How to solve this problem.

Comment: Please update your post with output of `ls -al /usr/local/cuda-8.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcudnn.so.6`. How did you get this file? From which package? Try to find it with `dpkg -S /usr/local/cuda-8.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcudnn.so.6` and post output in question.

Comment: After typing `ls -al /usr/local/cuda-8.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcudnn.so.6` on terminal i get `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 154322864 Nov 16 20:34 /usr/local/cuda-8.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcudnn.so.6` and after typing `dpkg -S /usr/local/cuda-8.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcudnn.so.6` i get `dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /usr/local/cuda-8.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcudnn.so.6
` .  i am getiing above mention comment while i am installing opencv from [this](https://linuxhint.com/how-to-install-opencv-on-ubuntu/) this tutorial

Comment: Waiting for reply

Comment: I can't help more. I do not have cuda-8.0 compatible video card. Please try to use [search on asubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=libcudnn) and logic.

Comment: Did you install cudnn?  It is a separate install from CUDA.

Comment: @N0rbert thnx .

Comment: @Robert Crovella yes i install cudnn

Comment: Please someone answer. I am unable to solve problem.

Comment: I faced a similar problem. [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/805595/sbin-ldconfig-real-usr-lib-libstdc-so-5-is-not-a-symbolic-link) might help.

Comment: How did you solve it Hitesh? I'm getting same error.

Comment: didin't solve yet.